# Valid IANA timezone list

Tags: node.js, timezone, moment-timezone

I'm working on an Nodejs system support multi timezone users. Currently, I'm using [moment.tz.names()](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/getting-zone-names/) to get list of available timezone. But I found out that some timezone in list is deprecated by this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). I also found [this database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) from IANA. So is there anyway to keep my timezone data up to date? I'm trying to find a way to work with IANA database.
Thank you if there are any other approaches.

Comment: Moment.js is no longer maintained, so the problem is likely to get worse.

Comment: I knew it, but my system is using moment to deal with timezone problems. We are moving to date-fns, I don't know if date-fns have a timezone list themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take a look at the [tzdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vvo/tzdb) package. It includes all IANA zones and is automatically updated on changes. You can get a list of timezones easily:

```
const { getTimeZones } = require("@vvo/tzdb");
const timeZones = getTimeZones();

console.log("Timezone (Berlin):", timeZones.find(tz => tz.name === "Europe/Berlin"));
console.log("Timezone (LA):", timeZones.find(tz => tz.name === "America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Comment: I found this package days ago but I don't know whether it is still valid. I will give it a try today.

Comment: Thank you, package include a const called timeZonesNames which is my target.