# What are all the available IANA time zones in Canada?

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization

I'd like to be able to tell if a user is in Canada and show an English-French language toggle for those users. So I've decided to use the [`Intl.DateTimeformat.resolvedOptions` approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions#description). It's pretty straightforward, if the user's system is says it's in a Canadian time-zone, then I want to respect that and assume they want to see this Canadian option. You can see a working demo below:

```js
const obj = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions();
console.log("Locale: ", obj.locale);
console.log("TimeZone: ", obj.timeZone);
```

I've asked some friends to test it, and so far I've got 2 timeZones

- `America/Toronto`
- `America/Vancouver`

but I need to cover *all* the Canadian options. I've looked at the [ECMA internationalization API](https://402.ecma-international.org/9.0/) and [IANA TimeZone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) but I cannot find what I'm looking for because their documentation is too vast. What are all the possible Canadian timezones that I could get from this specification?

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Also see: [Valid IANA timezone list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490421/valid-iana-timezone-list)

Comment: Note: it may be a bad idea. Something like default values are ok, but not displaying something according settings (which sometime are not controlled by users) is bad. A Canadian which work for some US company may have US time, but such user may want to see French. Or also a Canadian in US. As a user, I find very annoying when a system want to be smart, but it is not (hey Google!)